# PHP echo functions not working in php page loaded dynamically with jQuery .load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Here is the index.php and desktop.php of my wordpress installation. I'm loading desktop.php into #tLoad if browser window width is larger than 800px. So far so good. But I want to load it with a php echo. And in the desktop.php I want to use  etc, but it's not working either. I get an error that says "Fatal error: Call to undefined function.." and so on. I understand that I probably have to use AJAX calls of some kind, but I can't figure it out..

How can I make the php functions work inside the script and desktop.php?

```
<?php 
     /* Template Name: Start */
?>        
<?php get_header(); ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        function o() {
            if (ww > 800) {
                if ($.browser.device == false) {
                    e.load(n);
                } else {
                    e.load(r);
                }
            } else if (ww < 800) {
                e.load(r);
            }
        }
        isHome = true;
        var e = $("#tLoad"),

        // This is the first php echo that's not working (I have to put in the direct url to make it work):          
        n = "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/desktop.php",
        r = "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/mobile_v.php";

        $(window).resize(function() {
            ww = win.width();
            o()
        });

        o()
    });
</script>

<div id="tLoad"></div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

desktop.php:

```
<?php the_content(); ?>
```

Comment: You can't mix PHP (Serve Side Script) and Javascript (Client Side Script). Why don't you use PHP to get the Vieport of your Client?

Comment: hmmm, feel strange that even if your php is not called, those are variables, how can the error be "undefined function"?

Comment: How would I use PHP to get viewport of client?

Comment: You might want to consider using [`wp_localize_script()`](https://pippinsplugins.com/use-wp_localize_script-it-is-awesome/) for passing PHP variables over to JS. You'd have to enqueue your JS before using it though.

Answer (score 0):

> I get an error that says "Fatal error: Call to undefined function.."

`get_template_directory_uri()` is located in `wp-includes/theme.php`. You have to make sure theme.php is included before you call the function. Use

```
include_once "wp-includes/theme.php";
```

before you make a call to `get_template_directory_uri()`